# Grouping or Joining Search Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to have my websites search box be able to search multiple tables in one query.

So if a user searches for the users `display_name` which is stored in `ptb_profiles` they get any users with the matching name or if they search by nationality which is stored in `ptb_stats` they get all the users with that nationality displayed.

When i did this originally by using `SELECT * FROM ptb_users, ptb_stats, ptb_profiles` I got duplicate search results and the same results were being displayed multiple times, so I tried to do avoid this and have each result only displayed once by Grouping and using union all but that didnt work.

now ive tried this:

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT display_name, location, gender, contact_number FROM ptb_profiles WHERE display_name LIKE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR gender LIKE '%".$query."%' OR contact_number LIKE '%".$query."%' JOIN SELECT email, subscription FROM ptb_users WHERE email like '%".$query."%' OR subscription like '%".$query."%' JOIN SELECT nationality, hobbies, local_station FROM ptb_stats WHERE nationality like '%".$query."%' OR hobbies like '%".$query."%' OR local_station like '%".$query."%' 
        LIMIT 5");
```

but this just brings up the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PTB1/includes/mod_sidebar/search.php on line 31
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You've not shown us your schema, nor any code nor explain plans. The error you are getting is because your code is failing *BEFORE* it gets to mysql_fetch_array() and you've not included adequate checking.

Comment: Possible duplicate [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be the only way to do it. But you can do your search on multiple joined tables and fetch a distinct list of users easily if you apply a GROUP BY to your query. Assuming all your tables relate via an ID column something like this might work...

```sql
SELECT u.* FROM ptb_users u
INNER JOIN ptb_stats s ON s.user_id=u.id
INNER JOIN ptb_profiles p ON p.user_id=u.id
WHERE "this or that"
GROUP BY u.id
```

Change your joins to LEFT JOINS if its possible a user doesn't have a record in ptb_stats or ptb_profiles...

Comment: SELECT u.* FROM ptb_users AS u

Comment: If you're trying to state that the "AS" keyword is missing, please understand that the "AS" keyword is not actually required in SQL syntax. It's more of a relic from decades past.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` complains about `$query_for_result` not being a query result.
You must check the return value from `mysql_query()`. It returns false, if there's some problem with your SQL statement. So do at least

```
$sql = "select ...";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in $sql: " . mysql_error());
```

to prevent and diagnose such errors.